# Select data from database via AJAX (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have database with tables Companies, Vacancies, Interview and QuestionBlocks.

Here is scheme of it

[image]

So Vacancy is connected to Company, Interview connected to Vacancy and Question blocks connected to Interview.

I realize DropdownLists for Company and when I select company Vacancy dropdown list updates.

Here is code for View

```
<div style="width: 100%; margin-left: 20px;height: 15%;padding-top: 20px;">
    @Html.DropDownList("Company", ViewBag.Companies as SelectList, "Компания", new { @class = "greeting", @style = "width:30%; margin-left:20px;" })
    <select class="greeting" id="vacancy" name="id"  style="width:30%; margin-left:150px;" data-url="@Url.Action("Vacancies","Questions")">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Вакансия</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And Ajax call

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#Company").change(function (e) {
            var $vacancy = $("#vacancy");
            var url = $vacancy.data("url") + '?companyId=' + $(this).val();
            $.getJSON(url, function (items) {
                $.each(items, function (a, b) {
                    $vacancy.append('<option value="' + b.Value + '">' + b.Text + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have View like this

[image]

So what I need.

I need to make request to controller and find QuestionBlock  that related to VacancyId.

So as I understood I need to pass VacancyId from dropdownlist to controller make some sql operations and return JSON?

Or how I can do this?

**UPDATE**

Thank's for answer @CuriousDev, It works well for select item.

I need one more thing, I need to display Question1-Question10 like this.

[image]

Here is my Action method

```
public ActionResult QuestionBlocks(int vacancyId)
{
    var items = db.QuestionBlocks
        .Where(x => x.Interview.VacancyId == vacancyId)
        .Select(x => new 
        {
            ID = x.Block_ID.ToString(),
            Question1 = x.Question1,
            Question2 = x.Question2,
            Question3 = x.Question3,
            Question4 = x.Question4,
            Question5 = x.Question5,
            Question6 = x.Question6,
            Question7 = x.Question7,
            Question8 = x.Question8,
            Question9 = x.Question9,
            Question10 = x.Question10,
        })
        .ToList();
    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

How I need to write ajax call to back -end and display data in div?

Comment: So what's your question you have already found an solution and seems like you are aware of the solution

Comment: My question is how I need to make get request correctly and how I need to write method on server side? @Curiousdev

Comment: It'll be same as you have done in `vacancy` dropdown fill now in your case on change of `vacancy` you need to fill question than in replace of `$("#Company").change(function (e) {` you have to write `$("#vacancy").change(function (e) {` pass `vacancyid` in replace of `companyId` and here you go write your method with appropriate logic as the same way you have write for vacancy

Comment: I updated my post@Curiousdev

Comment: increase the height of your area which is showing the questions or decrease the height of rows, decrease paddings between them etc...

Comment: How it can helps me to display data from table?@MAdeelKhalid

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure whats failing your requirement, you have understanding for the logic its just the implementation which you need.

```
$("#Company").change(function (e) {
    var companyId = $(this).val();
    var model = {
        companyId:companyId
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Vacancies","Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false
    })
    .success(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(result.Vacancies);

    })
    .error(function (xhr, status) {
    alert("error");
});

});
```

For Controller

```
public ActionResult Vacancies(int companyId)
{
    // Logic to get the vacancies data
    var result = "abc";
    return Json(new { Vacancies = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I hope the above implementation helps you.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is ajax call to get json from Action Method it could be on dropdown change or some other events you wants on `Success` create your table structure and append it to the body as you wants below if just sample code

```
    $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("QuestionBlocks","YourController")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            type: 'Get',
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false
        })
        .success(function (result) {
           // Here do some stuff with your JSON to bind that in Table 
         var trHTML = '';

         $.each(data.Countries, function (i, item) {

          trHTML += 'Your Table Structure';
         });

          $('#YourID').append(trHTML);
        })
        .error(function (xhr, status) {
        alert("error");
     });
```

Comment: Thank's dude , I will try.